# An asymptotic estimate involving the Gamma function

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function

In one of the lecture notes I've found that $C_n$ 
$$
C_n=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n!}{\sqrt 2 \Gamma((n/2+1)}\pi^{-1/42^{-n/2}(n!)^{-1/2}} & n\text{ even}
\\[4mm]
\frac{2(n!)}{(\sqrt2n+1/(\sqrt2 n))\Gamma(n+1/2)}\pi^{-1/42^{-n/2}(n!)^{-1/2}}, 
& n\text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
is essentially $(n!)^{-1/2}$ for any $n\in N$.

I was trying to estimate $C_n$ and I was getting $C_n\approx\dfrac{(n!)^{1/2}}{2^{n/2}}$.

I cannot find my mistake. Please help me to understand how come $C_n\approx (n!)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: You used a relatively complicated "array" environment where a fairly simple "cases" environment gives better results.  And somehow you left the expressions "$n\text{ even}$" and "$n\text{ odd}$ _inside_ the superscripts.  Also I set "even" and "odd" as \text{ even} and \text{ odd}, with the initial blank space inside \text{}, so that the spacing is taken care of that way.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Thank you.